# Displaying multiple 3d plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, visualization, data-visualization

I am plotting 4 3d graphs into one window. Currently I have this result:

[image]

Code:

```
def multi_plot(fig, tuples3, pos, title):
    x, y, z = zip(*tuples3)
    z = map(float, z)
    grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[min(x):max(x):100j, min(y):max(y):100j]
    grid_z = griddata((x, y), z, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')

    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, pos, projection='3d')
    ax.set_xlabel('sets')
    ax.set_ylabel('percentage')
    ax.set_zlabel('accuracy')
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.plot_surface(grid_x, grid_y, grid_z, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))

multi_plot(fig, tuples3_1, 1, "Bagging - mincase 1")
multi_plot(fig, tuples3_2, 2, "Bagging - mincase 2")
multi_plot(fig, tuples3_3, 3, "Bagging - mincase 3")
multi_plot(fig, tuples3_4, 4, "Bagging - mincase 4")
plt.show()
```

Disregarding the last 2 weird looking graphs, there's a couple of points I'd like to change but can't find a way to do.

The label of the z-axis falls outside the designated white space for the graph, and the axes should be scaled down as they look too 'crowded'. 
As I'd like to include the graphs in my thesis, I am also looking for a way to change the grey background color to something more appealing.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Have you tried plt.tight()? If that fails, matplotlib also has kwargs hspace and wspace to increase space in height and width, respectively, as plt.subplot(hspace, wspace), that requires trial and error when used in conjunction with plt.plot(figsize).  Edit: plt.tight_layout()

Answer (score 0):

I managed to tweak a few things.

Setting the background color is as easy setting the facecolor of the 'fig' instance. And as mentioned by mikey in the comments, using plt.tight_layout() helps. I changed the following code by adding some calls to the mentioned methods.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))
fig.set_facecolor('white')
// method calls
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Resulting in this now:
[image]

I am going to leave the question open if someone has any nice tweaks to make it look better.